# React: Component with just a form, form submit action differs depending on consumer of the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I have a React Component which displays a simple search form. I am using "Controlled Components" (https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) so that the React component stores the search criteria and is the source of truth.

```
class SearchForm extends React.Component {    

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {criteria: ''};    
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({criteria: event.target.value});
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // only submit the search if there is search criteria
        if (this.state.criteria.length > 0){
            // I need to be able to set some state here
            this.setState({
                   .....
            });
            // i also need to access this.props here
            if (this.props......) ...
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >

                <input type="text" 
                       placeholder="Search"
                       value={this.state.criteria} 
                       onChange={this.handleChange} />

                <button ...... />
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

I want to use this SearchForm in 2 places.

- Search Box in a header : when the form submits it redirects to another page in my app
- Search box on the search page : when the form submits it updates the search list below the search form

Therefore the SearchForm's onSubmit method can not have the code to perform onForm submit as this code will vary depending on the SearchForms usage.

I know how to add the search form in my components HTML, For example in Component1's render method i would have

```
<div>
    <SearchForm />
</div>
```

However I do not know how to handle the SearchForms onSubmit differently for each component which is consuming the search form. Its like i want the SearchForm's onSubmit to call a method in the containing component passing the SearchForm's state.criteria value

How can i reuse the SearchForm component in other components which have different on form submit actions?

Comment: Just put additional parameter to your component `<SearchForm onSubmit={yourFunction} />` and then call it inside you `handleSubmit` function

Comment: And call your function inside the handleSubmit like this: `this.props.yourFunction()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can convert the search form to a function component and pass the submit handler as props. Using [Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) will be an ideal choice here.

```
 import React, { useState } from "react";

    export function SearchForm(props) {
      const [search, setInput] = useState('');

      const handleSubmit = (evt) => {
          evt.preventDefault();
          //validation here
         props.onSubmit(search)
      }
      return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
         <input
          type="text"
           placeholder="Search"
           value={search}
           onChange={(event) => setInput(event.target.value)}
        />

   <button/>
</form>;

      );
    }
```

and then you can use this search form in component with the desired on submit action like.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'

import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Header extends Component {

  constructor(props){
     super(props)
     this.state = {whatever: ''}
     this.onSearch = this.onSearch.bind(this)
   }

  onSearch(value){
   //you logic to navigate or display searched items
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchForm onSubmit={this.onSearch}>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is brilliant help thank you so much.

I have one issue though.  In the container component's onSearch where you have "you logic to navigate or display searched items" i can not seem to access that components state which i need to.   I have updated my original post to show that i need to access the state and props when the form is submitted

Comment: Ah i see i need to bind the function in my containing component so that it has access to "this"

componentWillMount() {
        this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
    }

Comment: @se22as Yes, you need to bind the function, but it is recommended to do it in the constructor. Also componentWillMount is deprecated. https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass callback function to your component as `props`, for example:

```js
class SearchForm extends React.Component {    

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {criteria: ''};    
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({criteria: event.target.value});
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // only submit the search if there is search criteria
        if (this.state.criteria.length > 0){
            this.props.onFormSubmit()
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >

                <input type="text" 
                       placeholder="Search"
                       value={this.state.criteria} 
                       onChange={this.handleChange} />

                <button ...... />
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

And component usage:

```html
<div>
  <SearchForm onFormSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit} />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you this is brilliant help. I have read up more on hooks.  The one thing i cant figure out is that in my containing components "handleFormSubmit" method, i can not access the components state or props (i.e.. this.props or this.state) the console this showing "this.setState is not a function" however that code worked fine before.  I have updated my original post to show that i need to access the state and props when the form is submitted

Comment: Ah i see i need to bind the function in my containing component so that it has access to "this"

componentWillMount() {
        this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
    }

Comment: I only marked the other answer as correct, as the Hooks documentation says you should use functions not classes.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding additional information here as I needed to do additional things to make my code work.

The answers above answered my question, but i had to do some extra things for the containing components to do as i require, such as

- access "this" in the components when the SearchForm calls back (i.e. the components "handleFormSubmit" method)
- display an initial value in the SearchForm's input box in one of the cases (i.e. on the search results page show the criteria passed to it)

*The reusable component defined as a function with Hooks (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)*

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function SearchForm (props) {   

    // if a value was passed into this component, use it as the initial search criteria
    const [searchCriteria, setSearchCriteria] = useState(props.value ? props.value : '');

    const handleSubmit = (evt) => {
        evt.preventDefault();

        if (searchCriteria.length > 0){
            props.onFormSubmit(searchCriteria)
        }
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

            <input type="text" 
                   value={searchCriteria}
                   onChange={(event) => setSearchCriteria(event.target.value)}/>

            <button />
        </form>
    );
}
```

*Usage 1: Search Box in a header* : when the form submits it redirects to the "Search Results Page"

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import SearchForm from './SearchForm'

class SearchBox extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        // bind the SearchForm's callback method, so in "handleFormSubmit" we can use "this"
        this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleFormSubmit(criteria){
        this.props.history.push('/searchresultspage/'+ criteria)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <SearchForm onFormSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit} />
        );
    }
}

// The following is needed so that the "this.props.history.push" in "handleSumbit" causes routing to happen
export default withRouter(SearchBox)
```

*Usage 2: Search box on the search results page*

- when search results page is first displayed, its search box should contain the search criteria passed to this page (i.e. from the search box in the header)
- search should be performed and results displayed
- user can change the search term in the search box and perform a new search

Code:

```
import React from 'react';

import SearchForm from './SearchForm'

export default class SearchResultsPage extends React.Component {

    state = {
        searchResults: [],
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // bind the SearchForm's callback method, so in "handleFormSubmit" we can use "this"
        this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);

        this.performSearch(this.props.criteria);
    }

    handleFormSubmit(criteria){
        this.performSearch(criteria)
    }

    performSearch(criteria) {
        // do whatever to do a search and get results (e.g. store in this.state.searchResults)
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {/* Pass the initial search criteria to the search form */}
                <SearchForm value={this.props.criteria} onFormSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit} />

                {/* do whatever to display the "this.state.searchResults */}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```